# Tomcat 9 Spring App Using WebApplicationInitializer Context Path Not Working

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat

I have a Spring 4.3.6 App that I'm migrating from a Tomcat 8.5 server, to a Tomcat 9.0.20 server on a different Linux host.

All works fine on the TC 8.5 server.

The docBase contains static html, and a war file. The war does unpack during startup, and the log shows "Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'". I can browse to the static content, but when browsing to the web app test page I get a 404 - see URLS:

[Static Content](https://tanglemydata.dev/)

[Web App Test Page](https://tanglemydata.dev/tanglemydataapp/login_cont/login_testpage)

Here's some of the catalina.log:

```
08-Jun-2019 18:54:09.548 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/home/carpenterdev/tanglemydata.dev/tanglemydataapp.war]
08-Jun-2019 18:54:19.968 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
08-Jun-2019 18:54:20.212 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
08-Jun-2019 18:54:20.216 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
08-Jun-2019 18:54:37.082 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
08-Jun-2019 18:54:37.285 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/home/carpenterdev/tanglemydata.dev/tanglemydataapp.war] has finished in [27,736] ms
08-Jun-2019 18:54:37.287 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/home/carpenterdev/tanglemydata.dev/assets]
08-Jun-2019 18:54:37.337 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/home/carpenterdev/tanglemydata.dev/assets] has finished in [50] ms
08-Jun-2019 18:54:37.363 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
08-Jun-2019 18:54:37.437 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
08-Jun-2019 18:54:37.505 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-127.0.0.1-8443"]
08-Jun-2019 18:54:37.564 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [71,758] milliseconds
```

Here's my Host element:

```
    <Host name="tanglemydata.dev" appBase="/home/carpenterdev/tanglemydata.dev" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
       <Context path="" reloadable="true" docBase="/home/carpenterdev/tanglemydata.dev" /> 
    </Host>
```

Here's what my docBase looks like:

[image]

Thanks for helping!

Bob

Answer (score 0):

I'm the OP, and have solved the problem.

Problem was due to the ServerName in the `<VirtualHost>` element in Apache2's httpd.conf, not matching the name specified in the `<Host>` element of Tomcat's server.xml.

The httpd.conf and server.xml must use the exact same name as registered with the DNS. In my original posting, you see that, in the server.xml, I specified:

```
<Host name="tanglemydata.dev"
```

But the httpd.conf gets it from the DNS, and it comes in as:

```
ServerName tanglemydata.carpenterdev.com
```

So, the change to sever.xml was this:

```
<Host name="tanglemydata.carpenterdev.com"
```

Plus, in server.xml I added an alias:

```
<Alias>tanglemydata.dev</Alias>
```

Hope this helps others.

Bob